# List of names when there is ownership associated

Tags: compound-possessives

Ok, so I am supposed to order business cards for people, then the company sends me the proof which I check over for correctness. When I do three on the people's names are right, one is wrong. So I want to write,

Angel, Jane, and Peter's cards are correct, but Jim's name is misspelled.

This doesn't look right to me. It makes me feel like Peter is owning all the possesive and not sharing with Angel and Jane, who have cards that are just as correct.

What would be the best way to write this sentence?

Thanks,

Rose.

Comment: So. You just answered your own question. Write "Angel's, Jane's, and Peter's cards".

Comment: _Angel, Jane, and Peter's cards are correct, but Jim's name is misspelled._ is grammatically correct, but means that there are two sets of cards, one ordered by Angel, Jane and Peter (cf Peter, Paul and Mary), and one by Jim.